# I made stored procedure, but I don't know what to put on my WHERE clause to filter the null column

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I made a INNER JOIN in stored procedure, but I don't know what to put to my WHERE clause to filter those column with null values and only shows those rows who has not null on a particular column.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[25]
@param1 int
AS
    SELECT c.Name, c.Age, c2.Name, c2.Country
    FROM Cus C 
    INNER JOIN Cus2 C2 ON c.id = c2.id
    WHERE c2.country is not null and c2.id = @param1
    Order by c2.Country 
RETURN 0
```

ID 1

```
+-----+----+---------+---------+
| QID | ID |  Name   | Country |
+-----+----+---------+---------+
|   1 |  1 | Null    | PH      |
|   2 |  1 | Null    | CN      |
|   3 |  1 | Japhet  | USA     |
|   4 |  1 | Abegail | UK      |
|   5 |  1 | Norlee  | Ger     |
+-----+----+---------+---------+
```

ID 2

```
+-----+----+----------+---------+
| QID | ID |   Name   | Country |
+-----+----+----------+---------+
|   1 |  2 | Null     | PH      |
|   2 |  2 | Null     | CN      |
|   3 |  2 | Reynaldo | USA     |
|   4 |  2 | Abegail  | UK      |
|   5 |  2 | Norlee   | Ger     |
+-----+----+----------+---------+
```

ID 3

```
+-----+----+----------+---------+
| QID | ID |   Name   | Country |
+-----+----+----------+---------+
|   1 |  3 | Gab      | PH      |
|   2 |  3 | Null     | CN      |
|   3 |  3 | Reynaldo | USA     |
|   4 |  3 | Abegail  | UK      |
|   5 |  3 | Norlee   | Ger     |
+-----+----+----------+---------+
```

I want when I choose any of the user in the C Table it will display the C child table data and remove the null name rows and remain the rows with not null name column.

Desired Result:

C Table (Parent)

```
+----+---------+-----+
| ID |  Name   | Age |
+----+---------+-----+
|  3 | Abegail |  31 |
+----+---------+-----+
```

C2 Table (Child)

```
+-----+----+----------+---------+
| QID | ID |   Name   | Country |
+-----+----+----------+---------+
|   1 |  3 | Gab      | PH      |
|   3 |  3 | Reynaldo | USA     |
|   4 |  3 | Abegail  | UK      |
|   5 |  3 | Norlee   | Ger     |
+-----+----+----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1: test not null value

Example:

```
   WHERE yourcolumn IS NOT NULL
```

Solution 2: test comparaison value in your where clause (comparaison substract null values)

Examples:

```
   WHERE yourcolumn = value 
   WHERE yourcolumn <> value
   WHERE yourcolumn in ( value)
   WHERE yourcolumn not in ( value) 
   WHERE yourcolumn between value1 and value2
   WHERE yourcolumn not between value1 and value2
```

Comment: WHERE yourcolumn <> value is what I needed. Thanks :D

Answer (score 4):

`WHERE column IS NOT NULL` is the syntax to filter out `NULL` values.

Comment: It didn't filtered out the null column.

Comment: Is it really `NULL` or is it just a standard text string that contains`"null"`? If the latter, you simply need to compare `column <> 'null'`

Comment: Ok, Sir. Thanks. I will try it again :D

Comment: @JaphetBatucan Just in case this is your situation, using the *string* "null" in a database instead of a database `NULL` will cause problems.

Comment: @AndrewMorton What should I do then? Please advise. Thanks

Comment: @JaphetBatucan You should ask a new question for that because it is a very different problem from this question. Include the database schema in your new question (just a `CREATE TABLE` statement will suffice - no need for a diagram)..

Comment: @AndrewMorton Ok. Thanks. I'll make new question.

Comment: @Aganju Thanks, Man. It solved my problem WHERE column <> ''